# Gas cost for bigInt library

Tags: solidity, gas, remix, bignumber

I am working on a **big integer** library in the online compiler.
Currently having gas/computational time issues with the modulus function.

I first implemented it using repeated subtraction:

```
function mod2(uint8[2] x, uint8[2] m) returns(uint8[2])
{
    // Check some special cases
    if (compa(m, [0, 0]) == 0)
        throw;
    if (compa(x, [0, 0]) == 0)
        return x;
    if (compa(m, x) == 0)
        return [0, 0];
    if (compa(m, x) == 1)
        return x;

    uint8[2] memory r = x;

    // Subtract
    while (compa(r, m) != -1)
        (r,) = sub(r, m);

    return r;
}
```

I then tried bit-shift and subtract:

```
function mod(uint8[2] x, uint8[2] m) returns(uint8[2])
{
    // Check some special cases
    if (compa(m, [0, 0]) == 0)
        throw;
    if (compa(x, [0, 0]) == 0)
        return x;
    if (compa(m, x) == 0)
        return [0, 0];
    if (compa(m, x) == 1)
        return x;

    uint8[2] memory r = x;
    uint8[2] memory n = m;

    // Align most significant bit
    while (compa(x, n) == 1 && n[n.length-1] & 0x80 != 1)
        n = shift(n, 1);
    if (compa(n, x) == 1)
        n = shift(n, -1);

    // Subtract
    while (compa(r, m) != -1)
    {
        (r,) =  sub(r, n);
        n =     shift(n, -1);
    }
    return r;
}
```

Complete contract [here](https://github.com/Metaception/ethereum-thesis/blob/master/BigInt/Modulus%20Comparsion.sol). Addition and subtract is **add()** and **sub()**; **shift()** is bitwise-shift with positive values being right and negative values being left. **Compa()** is a comparison function that returns 1 if greater, 0 if equal, and -1 if less than.

The end goal is to handle 1024-bit integers as four 256-bit integers.
I am using two 8-bit integers currently as it is much easier to debug.

For both cases, with a sufficiently large difference between the input and modulo (i.e. 255 % 4), the online compiler hangs and crashes.

The second implementation scales a bit better than the first one, but it seems to have a lot of overhead.

I was wondering if this was an issue with the online complier. Or if my code is just really slow? Even if I am using naive implementations, I didn't think the code would take this long to run or crash.

**Update:** Optimized the bitwise-shifts, 255 % 4 no longer crashes. Still quite slow though.