# Optimizing 512-bit bigInt library

Tags: solidity, gas, remix, bignumber

I mentioned [last time](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10518/gas-cost-for-bigint-library) that I was working on a **big integer** library.

After some work, I have managed get 512-bit arithmetic kinda working!!!!

Credits to /u/benjaminion for the modSmall function.

Here are the [**16-bit**](https://github.com/Metaception/ethereum-thesis/blob/master/BigInt/BigInt16.sol) and [**512-bit**](https://github.com/Metaception/ethereum-thesis/blob/master/BigInt/BigInt512.sol) versions. I develop in uint8 then port it to uint256 by replacing all the uint8.

Some issues I am currently facing and would like some help for:

- The modulo function is really slow for small modulus & large dividend
- The modular multiplication function is slow
- No division yet, should follow closely to modulo
- Gas costs are really high!

I am looking into other algorithms for modulo and modular arithmetic. 
I am not too knowledgeable in this area so help would be much appreciated!

Also, I was wondering how to get gas costs from Testrpc. The emulated VM in Remix(online compiler) tells me the gas costs, but it's too slow.

I may also have also messed up something when I was prettying up the code for Reddit or missed a few edge cases.
Any feedback is welcome!

**P.S.** I posted this in [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/5p7ycx/512bit_bigint_library/) too

Comment: I see you didn't implement division yet. Are you looking to implement it without using division?

Comment: My use case right now doesn't need division. I plan on adding it later with similar method to the modulo function

Comment: I asked because it's easy to implement mod() if you have div()

Comment: Yeah, I have a general idea of how to adapt the mod function to div. It's just that I am still optimizing the mod function and I am a little short on time.

Comment: Oh, I misread your post. I thought you said that it was easy to implement div() once you have mod(), but you said the opposite.

Comment: So my current mod() is basically division, I am simply not keeping track of the number of subtractions. If you know a division scheme with significantly better properties than bit-shift and subtract, then I would appreciate if you would share it. It's a real bottleneck for me right now.

Comment: Unfortunately bitshift and subtract is the most optimized method I'm aware of as well...